# Install crashlytics build in iOS simulator

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, ipa, crashlytics

How can install a Crashlytics build in an iOS simulator?

When I open the email invite I get in the simulator I get an error which says "Safari cannot open this page because the address is invalid"(screenshot attached).

[image]

The url looks like the one below,

[image]

I checked 'settings' for the Crashlytics profile and it seems that it is also not installed.

I tried to look for a way I could get a .ipa file from Crashlytics, but had no luck with that.

Comment: You can't install an app in your simulator from an email link. Why don't you use the .app file on your hard drive?

Comment: @B 7, Thank you for your help. Let say the .ipa file is not available and you only receive the crashlytics invite.

Comment: Did you check the content of the URL https://apps.crashlytics.com/projects/57d155.... ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot open an `itms-services://` link on the Simulator.  If you have received a Crashlytics beta invite, that app is only for use on actual device.

The reason is that device builds are build for the ARM architecture, while simulator builds are built for the i386 architecture.  Simulator and device builds are not compatible with each other.

Answer (score 2):

- In your webmail, copy the link target of the Install button in the Crashlytics mail
- Paste url in Safari in the Simulator. This will install the Crashlytics app in the simulator

If it doesn't work, add a comment with the link target that you found and I'll help you...

Comment: @B 7, Thanks for your help. I added the URL to the original question.